# If a MySQL/InnoDB 'lock wait timeout' happens, is the lock given anyway when it's free?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, innodb

We have a high performance Django web application that makes use of MySQL's InnoDB's row level locking. At a point in our code we see (in process A) if a particular row in a table is available by using `SELECT … FOR UPDATE`. If there is another process (B) that is using that row, and got there first, there will be an exclusive lock on that row, and A will have get a 'Lock wait timeout' exception. A will catch this, and move on to try another row (with a similar `SELECT … FOR UPDATE` approach).

However, I'm not 100% sure what happens when the lock wait timeout happens. After B is finished and releases it's locks, will an exclusive lock be given to A, even though A's 'select … for update' query has timed out, and A has moved on to lock another row?

*or* (and this is what I think intuitively happens), after A's attempt to get the lock fails, and it moves on, and B commits and finishes: Is there no further attempt to give the lock to A?

Preferable any reference/quote from the offical MySQL documentation would be best, since it's the canonical source. I couldn't find anything in the docs *specifically* addressing what happens when you attempt to get a lock and it times out.

Comment: "*Is there no further attempt to give the lock to A*". I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 3):

The lock requested by the statement that timed out will never be acquired:

> [When a lock wait timeout occurs, the current statement is rolled back.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout)

The below test exhibits this fact:

```sql
-- "atable" is an InnoDB table

-- Connection #1
BEGIN;
UPDATE atable SET acol = 1 WHERE acol = 2;

-- Connection #2
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM atable FOR UPDATE; -- hangs

-- Connection #3
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM atable FOR UPDATE; -- hangs

-- wait until Connection #2 times out
-- Connection #2
-- "Lock wait timeout exceeded"

-- Connection #1
COMMIT;

-- Connection #3 resumes execution and data is displayed
```